# Bootstrap CI for several variables of column in dataframe

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr, summary

I would like to bootstrap confidence intervals for a proportion from a `data.frame`. I would like to get the results for the variables in one of my columns.
I have managed to perform the bootstrap for a vector but do not know how to scale it up to a `data.frame` from here.
A simplified example setting a threshold value of 10 and looking at the proportion less than 10 in the data.

**Vector solution:**

```
library(boot)

vec <- abs(rnorm(1000)*10) #generate example vector

data_to_tb <- vec

tb <- function(data) {
  sum(data < 10, na.rm = FALSE)/length(data) #function for generating the proportion
}

tb(data_to_tb)

boot.out <- boot(data = data_to_tb, function(u,i) tb(u[i]),  R = 999)
quantile(boot.out$t, c(.025,.975))
```

And from here I would like to do the same for a `data.frame` containing two columns. 
I would like to return the result in a "summarized" `data.frame` if possible, with columns (x, sample, proportion, CI) :

```
x    n   proportion  CI

A    xx  xx          xx
B    xx  xx          xx
C    xx  xx          xx
```

Would be extra good if `dplyr` package could be used.
Here is a simplified example of my data:

**Example:**

```
dataframe <- data.frame(x = sample(c("A","B","C"),100,replace = TRUE), vec =abs(rnorm(100)*10))

head(dataframe)
##   x        vec
## 1 B 0.06735163
## 2 C 0.48612358
## 3 B 2.34190635
## 4 C 0.36393262
## 5 A 7.99762969
## 6 B 1.43293330
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `group_by` and `summarise` from `dplyr` to achieve the desired result. See below for the code.

```
# load required package
require(dplyr)
# function to calculate the confidence interval
CIfun <- function(v, probs = c(.025, .975)) {
  quantile(boot(data = v, function(u,i) tb(u[i]),  R = 999)$t, probs)
}
# using summarise from dplyr
dataframe %>% group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), 
            proportion = tb(vec), 
            `2.5%` = CIfun(vec, .025), 
            `97.5%`= CIfun(vec, .975))
```

Comment: @shadow Simplest example I've found online. Thanks very much for that, it works a treat with my dataset.